# Error: Unused arguments for function aggregate()

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the following script:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,1,2,1,3,12,14,16,30,21), nrow=5, ncol=2, byrow=FALSE);
colnames(m) <-c("Group","Score");
m<-data.frame(m)
head(m) 

sum1 <- aggregate(list(total_score=m$Score), by=list(group=m$Group), FUN=sum)
sum1
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Error in list(total_score = m$Score) : unused argument(s) (total_score = m$Score)
```

I've tried this script on 5 other people's machines, and the code runs just fine; I just don't know what's going on. I have the latest version of R, and this function doesn't require any additional packages beyond base R. Any thoughts from anybody?

Comment: It runs fine on my machine.  Could you have possibly overwritten the list function in your current workspace?  If you type "list" at the prompt, do you get "function (...)  .Primitive("list")"

Comment: I do not get any error as well.

Comment: Maybe you should post your R version number and your platform. Or the output of `R.Version()`.

Comment: And the output of `conflicts()` since it seems likely that `list()` got overwritten at some point.

Comment: kith pradan, this is the output....
    function(list1) {
        print(list1[,1])
    }

Comment: Brian Diggs, this is the output of conflicts():

    > conflicts()
    [1] "hist"      "body<-"    "c"         "kronecker" "list"           "try"

Comment: it is no problem for me, version of my R is R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16); platform: ubuntu 13.10, 64amd Shicheng Guo