# Error with "function" class

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the following script:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,1,2,1,3,12,14,16,30,21), nrow=5, ncol=2, byrow=FALSE);

colnames(m) <-c("Group","Score");
m<-data.frame(m)
head(m)


sum1 <- aggregate(list(total_score=m$Score), by=list(group=m$Group), FUN=sum)
sum1
```

But, when I run the script, the console returns the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class '"function"' into a data.frame
```

I haven't seen this error before.... any thoughts from anyone as to what is wrong?

Comment: I'm able to run this without any error with a fresh R session. Do you have any conflicting object names loaded?

Comment: So now you're running the exactly same code from your [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532316/error-unused-arguments-for-function-aggregate) question, but the error is different? Why didn't you just edit the original one?

Comment: You should test the class/output of each item individually if you want to pinpoint the problem. Do `list(total_score=m$Score)`, then `list(group=m$Group)`, and make sure you're getting the correct output for each argument of `aggregate`.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely overwrote one of the built in functions, like list() or sum().

One thing to note, R automatically loads a workspace called ".RData" when it starts up, and you might have saved the previously overwritten functions in that file.

Check the folder you're starting R from for any .RData files, and either delete them or rename them(They might be hidden!), so R isn't loading anything on startup.